# why the calendar in datapicker always appears when the webpage is loaded

Tags: jquery, calendar

I am annoyed by the initial appearance of the calendar UI generated by jqueryui when a webpage is initially loaded. This issue occurs in both IE and Chrome. Please help

```
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE" charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"></link>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date());
    });
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <p>Date: <input type="text" name="date" id="datepicker" ></p>
</body>
</html>
```

the initial look of the webpage is like this:

[image]

I don't want to see the calendar until user clicks the input box.
Please advise. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I found the root cause. It is because I used <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"></link>. By switching to <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />, this bug is fixed

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

is wrong, you are calling datepicker() twice. The second call shows the datepicker. What you want is this:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', new Date());
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but it didn't work. the calendar became a narrow strip but still there.